# Why is my SearchView expanded by default

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-softkeyboard, searchview

I am newbie to Android and working on a SearchView demo for learning purposes.
I have put a SearchView inside my Activity and I want that SearchView collapsed by default till the user expands it, but currently it is expanded by default.

So can anybody help me?

my code is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchViewSearchPosts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
        android:queryHint="Search.." >

    </SearchView>

       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentTimeline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**manifest**

```
 <activity
            android:name="one.tusk.stush.SearchPostActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="one.tusk.stush.activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing"
            android:label="Back">
            >
        </activity>
```

Comment: http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2015/08/simple-example-for-using-searchview-in.html may be this blog can help you

Comment: thing is that "collapseActionView|ifRoom" used for menu and i have take a standalone searchView controll not as a menu..so any idea?

Comment: why dont you close it with code when you land in the activity. check if it is open then close.

Comment: Please gimme the code sir..:( as have tried with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use android:iconifiedByDefault=true in layout xml

Comment: yes, you can check out at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setIconifiedByDefault(boolean)